# How to combine boolean and unit output of functions in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

It will be easier if I explain what I mean through an example.

So how can we a write function that takes an integer as a parameter and if that number is greater then 0 it return `true` and prints `Good!` and otherwise only returns `false`?

Comment: As a side note, whenever it's possible, try to keep pure functions pure. This means that when a function returns a value, try not to put side-effects in it (think as if someone used your function as a library and got "Good!" printed whenever it would be returning true, that's not a desired behaviour). In X. Van de Woestyne's answer, the first way of doing is considered the more "idiomatic" one and it will keep your code clean and easier to maintain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches. The first is to separate the problem, by providing a function that validates the answer and using a condition "outside" the function. For example:

```ml
let is_valid n = n > 0
(* And after *)
if is_valid 10 
then 
   print_endline "Good"
```

Otherwise, it is possible to display the result before returning the value, for example:

```ml
let is_valid n = 
  let result = n > 0 in
  let () = 
     if result 
     then print_endline "Good!"
  in result
```

In the second example, the final result (the boolean) is returned no matter what, but if the result is "true", the function will display "Good!".